# How to change font size of Data Views tab/window in Intellij?

Tags: fonts, intellij-idea

I don't know how to change it, variables display font is too small. Please advise.

EDIT:

To clarify: this is called "Data views". In preferences you go to **Debugger\Data Views**, but unfortunately there is no font adjustment available.

(this was advice of my experienced friend: use huge fonts, your eyes will be more relaxed so you won't need to wear glasses as many programmers do)

Comment: What is 'variables'?

Comment: When you run program in debug mode, then Variables window appears, where all current variables are displayed

Comment: Provide screenshot for more details

Comment: I have no rights to provide a screenshot, but I clarified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Preferences -> Appearance there is an option to override the default fonts:

[image]

The font and size you put here will be used in the Variables window during debugging (and many other windows too).

Comment: thanks, making default font bigger will help me also in other places. Even change from 13 to 14 makes difference, my eyes will be grateful after 10 years of coding

Answer (score 1):

I am using Custom Color scheme and this is not correct for me. For me I needed to
change in Settings: Editor -> Color Sheme -> Console Font

I checked 'Use console font instead of the default' and changed the size of the font.